# Define multiple variables using a string for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, append

I have a list of categories [A, B] and I want to Define multiple variables using a string for loop which is [A, B]. I was able to do it manually, however, it is not efficient especially if you have more than 2 categories. Could you please help me solve this issue?
here is what i did

```
RGB_A = []
for i in range(1,numGeoPics+1):
    g = gs.DataFile ('Outdir/Filters/RGB/addcoord_A{}.out'.format (i))['value']
    RGB_A.append (g)

RGB_B = []
for i in range(1,numGeoPics+1):
    g = gs.DataFile ('Outdir/Filters/RGB/addcoord_B{}.out'.format (i))['value']
    RGB_B.append (g)
```

and here is what I want to do :

```
Categories = ['A','B']
for Category in Categories: 
    RGB_['Category'] (here how to loop over categories list ?) = []
    for i in range(1,numGeoPics+1):
         g = gs.DataFile ('Outdir/Filters/RGB/addcoord_'+ str(Category)  +'{}.out'.format (i))['value']
         RGB_['Category'] (here how to loop over categories list ?).append (g)
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use a dictionary, or just not store the variables at all and just use a list?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to map the categories to variables.

```
categories = {'A': RGB_A, 'B': RGB_B}
for category, RGB in categories.items():    # .items() on a dictionary loops over the key and value together
    for i in range(1, numGeoPics + 1):
        g = gs.DataFile(f'Outdir/Filters/RGB/addcoord_{category}{i}.out')['value']
        RGB.append(g)
```

Comment: Got the idea thanks , however it says invalid syntax let me try again

Comment: @Karim_Mokdad_1995 put your new code and the traceback for the error in your original post so we can see

Comment: `categories = {'A': RGB_A, 'B': RGB_B}
for category, RGB in categories.items():    # .items() on a dictionary loops over the key and value together
    for i in range(1, numGeoPics + 1):
        g = gs.DataFile(f'Outdir/Filters/RGB/addcoord_{category}{i}.out')['value']
        RGB.append(g)`

Comment: and the error is NameError: name 'RGB_A' is not defined

Comment: @Karim_Mokdad_1995 well you still have to define RGB_A and RGB_B beforehand if you want to use them in the dictionary. Alternatively you can create lists right there in the dictionary like Mous mentioned, and only access them through the dictionary: `categories = {'A': [], 'B': []}`

Comment: Another thing I'd note is that you might not even need to name them `RGB_A` and `RGB_B` if it's sequential. Just make a list of what would be the values of that dict.